# How can I document a Fortran enum with doxygen

Tags: c++, enums, fortran, doxygen

I am trying to document a Fortran enum with doxygen with no success for now, google did not help.
Bellow is an example of Fortran enum:

```
enum, bind(c)
  enumerator :: OPTION1
  enumerator :: OPTION2
end enum
```

I tried inline comment for option and a block option in front of the enum but no luck.
Is it possible to have a nice documentation like one will have with C/C++ enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible the keyword enum is not yet supported for Fortran.

Comment: Thank you Albert. Although my problem is not solved, I stopped searching.